# How to save a boost::multi_array to a file

Tags: c++, boost, save, binaryfiles, boost-multi-array

I'm looking for a simple way to save to and load from a file a 3D boost::multi_array.
As far as I know there is no methods in the Boost library which I find odd.

I don't need the file to be human readable, so a binary file would be better for performance.
Can anyone point me to a ready-made solution or give me ideas on how to implement such read/write methods ?

I use 3D multi_arrays of types bool and ints so I'll need to use a template.

Comment: How about [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)?

Comment: Ok I'm reading this now. Looks like that's what I need.
I search for ways to "save boost_multi_arrays to files" but I had no idea serialization was the keyword.
Thanks

Comment: You can use an array library that supports serialization out of the box https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi#serialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unnecessary to use some special serialization libraries, because your data is already serialized in the memory and you can get it as follows (suppose `A` is the array containing `int` data:

```
int *data = A.data();
size_t size = A.num_elements();
```

You can just write it one by one to a file. A better way may be using `mmap`, like follows:

```
int fd = open("myfile", O_RDWR);
size_t bytes = size * sizeof(int);
ftruncate(fd, bytes);
void *buf = mmap(NULL, bytes, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
memcpy(buf, data, bytes);
close(fd);
munmap(buf, bytes);
```

It is very easy to reload the data from file to `A`. Just ommit the invocation of `ftruncate` and call `memcpy(data, buf, bytes);`.

An even better way is that, if your data is huge, you simply store the data in a file, use `mmap` to map it to a memory address, then pass the address to `multi_array_ref`. In this case you don't need to specifically write it to file. It is aromatically done by the OS.

The above code is considered for Linux, but I believe other platforms should have similar functionality. Error checking is omitted for clarity.

Comment: I assume that the element in the `multi_array` is plain-old-data without pointers to other memory locations. If your situation is more complicate than that, you will still need to write some particular serialization methods.